# how to show add to cart after login only in every page with magento

Tags: magento, magento-1.7, magento-1.8

I want to show add to cart button after login in every page in magento.
For that i have used below coding in `app\design\frontend\default\sagsupplies\template\catalog\product\view.phtml` page

```
<?php if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()) { ?>
   <?php if (!$this->hasOptions()):?>

                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php if($_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                        <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addtocart') ?>
                        <?php if( $this->helper('wishlist')->isAllow() || $_compareUrl=$this->helper('catalog/product_compare')->getAddUrl($_product)): ?>

                        <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php endif; ?>
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
                <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('extra_buttons') ?>
            <?php elseif (!$_product->isSaleable()): ?>
                <div class="add-to-box">
                    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('addto') ?>
                </div>
            <?php endif; ?>
<?php } ?> 
but it is not working.add to cart button still shows.I want to hide add to cart button in every page.If anyone knows this, please help me out.
```

Thanks!

Answer (score 3):

1.In app\design\frontend\default\sagsupplies\template\catalog\product\list.phtml,

add the line,

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

before

```
if($_product->isSaleable())
```

2.app\design\frontend\default\sagsupplies\template\catalog\product\view\addtocart.phtml

add the line

```
if (Mage::getSingleton('customer/session')->isLoggedIn()):
```

before

```
<button type="button" title="<?php echo $buttonTitle ?>" class="button btn-cart" onclick="productAddToCartForm.submit(this)"><span><span><?php echo $buttonTitle ?></span></span></button>
    <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('', true, true)
```